# How to get intellisense feature in Chrome's "developer bar" console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

Hi all in Firefox we have an "auto-complete" feature when using the Firebug console.

I was wondering does anyone know if we have this functionality on the Chrome's "developer bar" ( <kbd>F12</kbd> ) as well?

http://aviary.me/sFJlI6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup it is there, but not as good as Firebug, Below is the screen shot, It kind of shows only on property at a time. You need to navigate with the arrow keys to get to that particular property. below link has on the right side has an excellent video to get started with Inspect element in Chrome by paul Irish.

[Chrome Dev Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, dang chrome really need to buck up on this aspect.